# Choosing a CAPTCHA Page Image

Tags: discussion, top-7

We need to choose a CAPTCHA image.

To clarify, what we're looking for is an amusing picture to go on the CAPTCHA page...along with the CAPTCHA. The image will just be for added comedic effect; it won't be the CAPTCHA itself (the CAPTCHA is from reCAPTCHA). Check out the "HELLO FELLOW ROBOT" image on the current captcha page: [gis.stackexchange.com/captcha](https://gis.stackexchange.com/captcha)

It would be interesting if we could find an image that visually demonstrated the idea of a CAPTCHA.

[(Vote on other Site Attributes)](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/)

Comment: How is this gis related?

Comment: @CrazyEnigma it's about the site, which is why the question is on meta.gis... To successfully survive a beta we as a community need to decide on such things as site name, look, feel, etc. which includes a CAPTCHA -- see also: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1/

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I got started in reading the meta and didn't finish.

Answer (score 7):

How about something on the satnav theme?, Maybe:
[image: The Homing Pigeon Has SatNav]

Comment: +1, perfect I think!